# C#, How Do I Get Mono Configured on Windows Powershell (Windows 10)? (Environmental Variable PATH)

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, mono

I installed mono-4.6.2.16-x64-0.msi on my desktop. I tried to add an environmental variable by going to Control Panel > Systems > Advanced Systems > Environmental Variables > PATH > Edit > Add > C:\Users\myAccount\Desktop (where I installed Mono) then after clicking OK, I opened Windows Powershell but the PATH was not set.. and when I typed "mono --version" it gave a message "The term 'mono' is not recognized.' What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

By defaul the mono-4.6.2.16-x64-0.msi install mono in `C:\Program Files\Mono`. If you add the path `C:\Program Files\Mono\bin` to your user path, you can then start mono from PowerShell and it works.

Now you just have to adapt this to your installation.